# Error while using body.json() for parsing response from http.get()

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, observable, httpmodule

Tried using body.json() to assign data to an array of object but as it returns a promise tried this. But browser throws error telling me json() is not a function.

```js
getRecipes() {
  this.http.get('https://recipe-book-1be52.firebaseio.com/recipes.json').subscribe(
    (response: Response) => {
      response.json().then(
        (data) => {
          this.recServ.setRecipes(data)
        }
      );
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: `json()` is not required in the new versions of `HttpClient`. Also you don't have a promise to call `then()` here. You could directly do `(response: Response) => { this.recServ.setRecipes(response) }`

Comment: Argument of type 'Response' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Recipe[]'.
  Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'Recipe[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2345)...getting this error

Comment: Try changing `response: Response` either to `response: Recipe[]` or `response: any` or just `response`.

Comment: solved thanks a ton :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually replace it like this, Also, can assign response to an interface to strict-type it.

```
getRecipes() {
  this.http.get('https://recipe-book-1be52.firebaseio.com/recipes.json').subscribe(
    (response) => this.recServ.setRecipes(response)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

angular httpClient already does the .json() for you

Answer (score 1):

Below code snippet may help you

```
  getRecipes() {
    this.http.get('https://recipe-book-1be52.firebaseio.com/recipes.json').subscribe(
      (response: Response) => {
            this.recServ.setRecipes(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)));
      }
    )}
```